# cannot open source file "stdio.h" in one file in a directory

Tags: c, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-extensions, compiler-warnings

I am running wsl on vscode. I have a directory consisting of two c files with similar content. Both are using the `stdio`. But only one of them is showing error squiggles. If I am creating a new file the new files are also showing error.

This is the include paths in my extension:

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

This is the output of `echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -`

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include-fixed/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 0 "<stdin>"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

I am expecting no error squiggles.

Comment: Can you report the errors that you are getting? It might be best to start by analyzing these.